# Setting detail API View to str instead of pk with Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I've got my API list view set up to url 'api/', and I want to change the detail (RetrieveAPI) view from url 'api/'pk'/' to 'api/'name'/ where name is a field in my model.

I've tried various combinations of

```
lookup_url_kwarg = 'name'
```

and

```
lookup_field = 'name'
```

in both my serializers.py and views.py, but either I get a 404 response, or the url is still api//. Also if the field is a string, will I have to include quotation marks in my urls? Any insight would be great!

serializer.py:

```
    class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields =('name', 'topLevelDomain', 'alpha2Code', 'alpha3Code', 'callingCodes',
             'capital', 'altSpellings', 'region', 'subregion', 'population', 'latlng',
             'demonym', 'timezones', 'borders', 'nativeName', 'numericCode',
             'currencies', 'translations', 'flag', 'regionalBlocs', 'cioc')
        lookup_field = 'name'
```

views.py:

```
class CountryListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer


class CountryDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer
    #lookup_url_kwarg = 'name'
```

url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CountryListView.as_view()),
    path('<name>/', CountryDetailView.as_view())
]
```

Comment: Can you please include the relevant parts of the list view/viewset and serializer? Also you should probably verify that the instance that generates the url actually has a value for the property you're trying to use.

Comment: I added the code to the original part. How do I verify the instance, just by going to the url?

Comment: You'd do it in the shell or in the database. Look up the instance(s) you're trying to render into json and check the value of the property.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lookup_field`. Verify that `/api/` displays the list of countries. Then try `/api/<country_name>/` where country_name is the name of one of the instances of `Country`.

```
class CountryDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer
    lookup_field = 'name'

class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        ...
        lookup_field = 'name'
```

Comment: I checked in shell and .values() gives a value for 'name', but now when I try /api/<country_name>/ it doesn't work